# How to un-install a Nuget Package?

Tags: package, nuget

I have been adding packages using Nuget, but I want to remove some packages. But I simply unable to find the "remove" button. The packages with a green mark indicates they are added to the project. But how can I "Remove" them using Nuget? Is Nuget designed to give me a one-way ticket?

[image: A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the **Installed packages** tab you will see an uninstall button.

Answer (score 0):

See the help documentation on Nuget.org

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Managing-NuGet-Packages-Using-The-Dialog

Make sure you have the latest version of NuGet installed.